# Linux driver using UART

Tags: linux, file, driver, uart

I'm starting with an embedded custom board (based on ZynqMP SoC) which uses PIC24 micro as power manager and RTC, among other things, like some buzzers and battery management. The communication with the micro is via an UART which has its own xilinx driver, which as usually exports the tty to the dev folder.

I understand that I need to create an RTC driver, and that driver must communicate with the micro with the UART. What would be the best way to do that? I've thought about opening the dev file from my driver and use it there, but i've read in several places that dealing with the filesystem on the kernel is not a good idea.

Moreover, using the dev file is kind of ugly because actually no one in the userspace should use it, i'm exporting a file to userspace which only must be dealt with in kernel space.

EDIT:

Another problem, could the RTC driver even access the filesystem to open the UART? I understand that driver would run before the filesystem exists.

Comment: I have done something similar with TI boards in order to initialize the RTC. Essentially I use the UART, but use a simple serial program (minicom) which is no different that PuTTY, etc... I have the embedded system watch for the string `"RTC"` being sent from the PC indicating the date and time will follow. I then transmit the current PC date/time. The equivalent to `echo "RTC $(date '+%w %Y %m %d %H %M %S')"` on Linux. The key on the embedded board is to start a timer when the date/time is received and add 1-sec to time. Delay until the timer expires and set the onboard RTC.

Comment: Standard Linux way is coupling drivers with bus on device-tree level. This is the thing I would search for. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/devicetree/usage-model.html#device-population

Comment: @Nabuchodonozor There wasn't a serial bus until recently (4.12) and the UART driver we want to use is not attached to that bus.